# A proof for increasing the Evidence Lower Bound always results in increment in the log marginal likelihood

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

I have the confusion about the $\mathrm{ELBO}$. Let's say if we have the observed data $x$, the hidden variable $z$ with underlying parameters $\theta$. The log marginal likelihood function is defined as $l(\theta|x):=\ln p(x|\theta)$. With an arbitrary density function of the hidden variable $z$, $q(z)$, it is not hard to derive the following relation

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \ln p(x|\theta)\\
&= \int q(z) \ln p(x|\theta)dz\\
&= \int q(z) \ln \frac{q(z)}{q(z)}\frac{p(x,z|\theta)}{p(z|x,\theta)}dz\\
&= \int q(z)\ln\frac{p(x,z|\theta)}{q(z)}dz+\int q(z)\ln\frac{q(z)}{p(z|x,\theta)}dz\\
&:= \mathrm{ELBO}(q)+\mathrm{KL}(q\|p(z|x,\theta))
\end{aligned}
$$

The explanation for increasing the $\mathrm{ELBO}$ is that since the $\mathrm{KL}$ divergence is always nonnegative, maximizing $\mathrm{ELBO}$ is equivalent to minimizing the $\mathrm{KL}$ divergence. And the increase of $\mathrm{ELBO}$ always results in an increase of the log marginal likelihood.

For Expectation and Maximization (EM) algorithm, let $q(z):=q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})$, then we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
&l(\theta|x)\\ 
&= \int q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})\ln\frac{p(x,z|\theta)}{q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})}dz+\int q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})\ln\frac{q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})}{p(z|x,\theta)}dz\\
&= \int q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})\ln p(x,z|\theta)dz-\int q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})\ln q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})dz+\int q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})\ln\frac{q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})}{p(z|x,\theta)}dz\\
&:=Q(\theta|\theta^{(t)})+H(q)+\mathrm{KL}(q(z)\|p(x,z|\theta))
\end{aligned}
$$
So maximizing the $\mathrm{ELBO}$ is equivalent to maximizing $Q$ since the entropy term $H$ is a constant.
The Maximizing step is to find $\theta^{(t+1)}$ such that

$$
\left.\frac{\partial Q(\theta|\theta^{(t)})}{\partial \theta}\right|_{\theta^{(t+1)}}=0
$$

The expectation step is

$$
Q(\theta|\theta^{(t)})=\mathbb{E}_{q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})}\left(\ln p(x,z|\theta)\right)
$$

To make the sentence "The increase of $\mathrm{ELBO}$ always results in an increase of the log marginal likelihood" solid, it would be nice if we can prove the following statement:
For $\theta^{(t+1)}$ and $\theta^{t}$, it must be that $l(\theta^{(t+1)}|x)\ge l(\theta^{t}|x)$. Where can I find the proof for this? My thoughts

$$
\begin{aligned}
&l(\theta^{(t+1)}|x)-l(\theta^{t}|x)\\
&= \int q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})\ln \frac{p(x,z|\theta^{(t+1)})}{p(x,z|\theta^t)}dz+\int q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})\ln\frac{p(z|x,\theta^{(t)})}{p(z|x,\theta^{(t+1)})}dz\\
\end{aligned}
$$

The first term is obvious nonnegative. How do we deal with the second term?

Comment: One of the first papers that describe the EM algorithm should contain a proof of this: [Maximum Likelihood from Incomplete Data Via the EM Algorithm by Dempster et al. (1977)](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2517-6161.1977.tb01600.x).

Comment: Hint: Jensen's inequality.

Comment: I just realized in the EM algorithm $q(z)=p(z|x,\theta^{(t)})$ not the $q(z)=q(z|x,\theta^{(t)})$. So the second term should be straightforward by using Jensen's inequality.